# Crashlytics performs network request for settings every time it been initialized

Tags: android, crashlytics, google-fabric, crashlytics-android

I'm initializing Crashlytics every time my procees starts from the `Application.OnCreate()` method using the following code:

> ```
>   Fabric.with(new Fabric.Builder(MainApplication.getAppContext()).debuggable(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
>                                                                    .logger(BuildConfig.LOGS_ENABLED ? new DefaultLogger(Log.VERBOSE) : new SilentLogger())
>                                                                    .kits(new Crashlytics.Builder().build())
>                                                                    .build());
> ```

I noticed in the logs and netowrk traffic monitor tools that every time I'm doing this initialization - the following happen:

```
D/Fabric: Requesting settings from https://settings.crashlytics.com/spi/v2/platforms/android/apps/..
```

then

```
D/Fabric: Loaded settings: {"settings_version":2,"cache_duration":7200,..., .....,"expires_at":1524658871212..}
```

it looks like the cache duration is 7200 (Milliseconds?)  which explains why every time it download from scratch.

this is a problem for me, because I would like to avoid any network requests that opens 3G/WIFI radio when not really needed. my process wakes up a lot, and I would like to not drain the battery.

I would expect it will be possible to modify the cache duration somehow, but I did not found any way in the Fabric console or programatic to do that.

I'm using Crashlytics version 2.6

My questions are:

- I'm I missing here something?
- Is it possible to modify somehow the cache duration of the settings or prevent every initialization from load the settings from scratch?

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. Things should back off once the initial configurations are done, if you can share your package name or bundle id, then I can dig in more.

Comment: Hi Mike.   I've been hoping to get answer or clue from an insider.   Where can I send you privately the package name?

Comment: Support(at)Fabric(dot)io but in my digging, I realized what's going on. With debug mode, our caches are being ignored which is why you're seeing the calls happen at the given frequency.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I was suspecting that this might be the reason, so I tried to remove the call to Fabric.Builder(MainApplication.getAppContext()).debuggable(BuildConfig.DEBUG) setter and nothing changed - still each initialization triggered the call.   Is it makes sense? Is crashlytics detects in other way the app is debuggable?

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting. Are you using Crashlytics only or Answers as well on your dashboard? That is, do you see the Retention, Growth, Latest Release pages active or greyed out?

Comment: I have "Answers" enabled. just sent email to fabric support with the title -  "Crashlytics performs network request for settings every time it been initialized"  so you can see my app's package name. Thanks in advance